# How do I embed a terminal on the desktop?

Tags: 11.04, command-line

I've tried the tutorials that I've found via Google search, but none of them seem to work on 11.04. Anyone know how it's done?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean something like this ? http://www.screenlets.org/index.php/Terminal ? Please, describe it better

Comment: Exactly like that!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here you go

http://www.screenlets.org/index.php/Terminal

( if there wont be better answer, mark this as answered )